# How to add a directory from remote host to local in PHP Storm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I have set up a project in PHP Storm. I have my local files synced to the remote directory. I have excluded some of the directories on the remote host. Now I have decided I need to add one of these directories.

I go to `tools > deployment > configuration` and choose the `Excluded Paths` tab. I select the directories I no longer want to exclude and hit `ok`. Now when I browse my remote host I can see that the files are indeed no longer excluded. But they haven't been copied to my local directory.

My question is, how to I download a directory from the remote host to my local directory without syncing the whole project again?

**UPDATE**

I still cannot download these directories but can manage with a work around. To drag and drop from the remote host to the local directory without moving the folders - just copying them - drag and hold `ctrl` before you drop in the target directory: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/01/drag-and-drop-to-remote-hosts-changes/

I am new to PHP Storm and love it so far but some simple tasks really take a while to get your head around. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: `Right click | Download` when browsing Remote Host ?

Comment: @LazyOne Yea you would think that'd work but it doesn't. I get a message that says `1 item excluded, No files or folders found to process`. Even though the folder is not excluded

Comment: Also, dragging from the remote host to the local doesn't copy files or folders but moves them. But videos and tutes I've seen show that it copies it?

Comment: 1) Possibly you have another exclusion rule that overlaps somehow (e.g. local) or maybe it contains files that are excluded by file mask 2) try restarting IDE 3) Keep `Ctrl` pressed when drag&drop files to copy them (no real clue why devs decided that it should work this way).

Comment: @LazyOne yea the holding `Ctrl` thing is a new one to me. Thanks.

Comment: Please post screenshots with all deployment settings/all tabs/subscreens (black-out personal stuff if desired; plus you may remove such images later)

Comment: As for `Ctrl` usage -- watch this ticket for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22133